# redirect in htaccess to force uppercase URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all address in my website from lower case to upper case and with no slash at the end of the URL.

For example, I want to change

```
example.com/aaa
```

To

```
example.com/AAA/
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Apache 2.4

If you are using Apache 2.4 then you can use an *Apache expression* (with mod_rewrite) in `.htaccess` and make use of the `toupper()` function.

I assume you will need to exclude any requests that would otherwise map to real files or directories from the uppercase conversion, otherwise these will likely fail on a case-sensitive OS.

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Convert virtual URL paths to uppercase and append a slash if omitted
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond expr "toupper(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ m#(.+)/?$#"
RewriteRule [a-z] %1/ [R=301,L]

# Append a trailing slash if omitted
# - Exclude any requests that "look-like" a static resource / actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

The first rule redirects any URL containing lowercase letters, excluding requests that map to actual files or directories, to the same - all uppercase - URL. The trailing slash is also appended if omitted.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `[a-z]` simply checks there is at least one lowercase letter in the requested URL-path. The `RewriteCond` directive then calls the `toupper()` function on the URL-path (`REQUEST_URI` server variable), using an Apache expression, the result of which (less a trailing slash, if any) is then effectively *captured* using the regex `(.+?)/?$`.

The `%1` backreference in the *substitution string* then holds the result of the `toupper()` function call, less an optional trailing slash (as stored by the capturing group in the preceding condition), ie. the uppercase URL-path.

The second rule appends the trailing slash if omitted and applies to URLs that are already uppercase and don't "look-like" actual files.

Only at most 1 redirect occurs.

---

#### Apache 2.2

It's easier to treat this as two separate tasks / redirects:

1. Convert URL to uppercase.
2. Append a trailing slash, if omitted.

We presumably need to be careful not to convert requests for actual filesystem resources - unless that is a requirement here?

Unfortunately, if you are restricted to using `.htaccess` on Apache 2.2 then there is no simple directive to convert lowercase to uppercase. You need to iterate over the URL, internally rewriting each letter as required. Then you can issue a single redirect when done.

Add the following to the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request "looks-like" a file (ie. has a file extension) then abort now...
RewriteRule \.\w{2,4}$ - [L]

# If there are lowercase letters, set HAS_LC to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [a-z] - [E=HAS_LC:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no lowercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![a-z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurrence of letter, then process next Rule.
# DPI flag required if requesting multiple virtual path segments (ie. with path-info)
RewriteRule ([^a]*)a(.*) $1A$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^b]*)b(.*) $1B$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^c]*)c(.*) $1C$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^d]*)d(.*) $1D$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^e]*)e(.*) $1E$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^f]*)f(.*) $1F$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^g]*)g(.*) $1G$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^h]*)h(.*) $1H$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^i]*)i(.*) $1I$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^j]*)j(.*) $1J$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^k]*)k(.*) $1K$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^l]*)l(.*) $1L$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^m]*)m(.*) $1M$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^n]*)n(.*) $1N$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^o]*)o(.*) $1O$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^p]*)p(.*) $1P$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^q]*)q(.*) $1Q$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^r]*)r(.*) $1R$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^s]*)s(.*) $1S$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^t]*)t(.*) $1T$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^u]*)u(.*) $1U$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^v]*)v(.*) $1V$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^w]*)w(.*) $1W$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^x]*)x(.*) $1X$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^y]*)y(.*) $1Y$2 [DPI]
RewriteRule ([^z]*)z(.*) $1Z$2 [DPI]

# If there are any more lowercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
# Set internal limit of 30 loops (requires Apache 2.4.8)
# Increase limit if you have more than 30 instances of any one letter in the URL. (eg. > 30 "a")
RewriteRule [a-z] - [N=30]

# If a conversion has occurred then issue an external redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:HAS_LC} TRUE
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]

# Append a trailing slash if omitted
# - Exclude any requests that "look-like" a static resource / actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,L]
```

Note that you should ideally test first with 302 (temporary) redirects in order to avoid any potential caching issues.

This lowercase to uppercase solution is based on the code at
https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/

Comment: Thanks for your answe MrWhiter. When I try to run it I get this error in the URL: mydomain.net/INDEX.PHP?/INDEX.PHP/

Comment: The previous code executed unconditionally to uppercase the requested URL - It looks like this was conflicting with your DirectoryIndex and/or front-controller. I've updated the code to exclude requests for what "look like" actual files. I've also included the `DPI` flag to allow requests for multiple virtual path segments. eg. `/foo/bar/baz` and not just `/foo` (a single path segment - as in your example). Please copy the entire code block again as I've made various changes throughout.

Comment: Let me know if you're still having problems with this and provide detail of the URLs you are requesting and the full contents of your `.htaccess` file - please edit your question to add this information. Knowing your file structure may also be required.